# value check in a nested JSON using Postman

Tags: postman

I have a nested JSON that from GET request,in POSTMAN

```
"ID": [
        {
            "value": "xxx",
            "id": "1111111",
            "manager": [
                {
                    "valueId": "1",
                    "blockId": "xx",
                    "blockTypeId": "xxxx",
                    "settings": {
                        "ISlogin": false,

                        }
                    },
```

I am trying to test whether my response body has "ISlogin":fasle

```
tests["ISlogin"] = jsonData.ID[0].manager[0].settings.ISlogin =  "false";
pm.expect(ID[0].manager[0].settings.ISlogin).to.eql('false');
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Can you format your question a bit better, and tell us about what you have already tried?

Comment: Can you post what you've tried so far? Are you getting any errors?

Answer (score 1):

Given the sample data, to check if the value is `false`, you could use this:

```
pm.test("Check if false", () => {
    var jsonData = pm.response.json();
    pm.expect(jsonData.ID[0].manager[0].settings.ISlogin).to.be.false;
});
```